# [play framework 1.2.5]'play start' does not work properly (windows XP)

Tags: playframework, production-environment, self-hosting

When I start my play application with following command in production mode.

`play start 'path to application' -Dprecompiled=true`

following output comes on command prompt:-

```
C:\Documents and Settings\328982>play start C:\328982\RCM\RCMComm\branches\Code\
WorkingCopy\RCMCommercial -Dprecompiled=true
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.2.5, http://www.playframework.org
~ framework ID is prod
~
~ OK, C:\328982\RCM\RCMComm\branches\Code\WorkingCopy\RCMCommercial is started
~ output is redirected to C:\328982\RCM\RCMComm\branches\Code\WorkingCopy\RCMCom
mercial\logs\system.out
~ pid is 4244
~
```

But when i close command prompt, application also stops.

Please guide me on how to host play application [version 1.2.5] in production mode on inbuilt server jboss netty.

Regards,
Uttmesh

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the output (logs/system.out)? My guess is that because you are running in production mode, it's trying to bind to port 80, which you can't unless you are running play as admin.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.

I have checked Logs and there is no 'BindingException' in log
More over I have not given any setting to bind port:

# Server configuration
# ~~~~~
# If you need to change the HTTP port, uncomment this (default is set to 9000)
# http.port=9000

Regards, Uttmesh